# Ajax Form Submit with upload file multipart/form-data

Tags: ajax, forms, payload

I have this simply form

[image: Form]

```
<form id="my-form-1" class="ajax-form my-form p-4 p-md-5 bg-light text-dark rounded shadow-sm fs-6" action="https://www.gmondini.local/contact-form/send/1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" _lpchecked="1">
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="mt-4 p-3 btn btn-primary text-uppercase text-white">Send Message</button>

    <div class="mt-4 d-none alert alert-success" role="alert">
        Thank you for your message. It has been sent.
    </div>
    <div class="mt-4 d-none alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.
    </div>
</form>
```

I create this function in javascript to transform form into a call ajax

```
document.querySelector('.ajax-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = this;
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    let parsedData = {};
    for (let name of formData) {
        if (typeof(parsedData[name[0]]) == "undefined") {
            let tempdata = formData.getAll(name[0]);
            if (tempdata.length > 1) {
                parsedData[name[0]] = tempdata;
            } else {
                parsedData[name[0]] = tempdata[0];
            }
        }
    }

    let options = {};
    switch (this.method.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'post':
            options.body = JSON.stringify(parsedData);
        case 'get':
            options.method = this.method;
            options.headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
            break;
    }

    var error = form.querySelector(".alert-danger");
    var success = form.querySelector(".alert-success");
    var submits = form.querySelectorAll('[type="submit"]');
    fetch(this.action, options).then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
        if (typeof data.success == 'undefined' || !data.success) {
            success.classList.add("d-none");
            error.classList.remove("d-none");
        } else {
            success.classList.remove("d-none");
            error.classList.add("d-none");
            submits.forEach(toremove => {
                toremove.classList.add("d-none");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

But when i click submit and see payload this happens
[image: payload]

File is always empty!

Also in backend (laravel 8.0) this

```
$files = $request->file('filebig');
var_dump($files);die;
```

return NULL;

How can I fix this? multipart/form-data is setted correctly!

Thank u